# Write custom library on top of open source ones

Tags: python, command-line-interface, open-source, python-packaging, mlflow

I want to use `mlflow` at work for experiment tracking, it's an opensource library to track machine learning experiments. The problem with `mlflow` is that it doesn't support snowflake as database. Thus, I have decided to create my `custom-mlflow` library where I add snowflake support.

However, I am struggling a bit to organize my project.

Right now, the structure looks a bit like that:

```
project/
|-- pyproject.toml 
|-- src/
```

What I aim to do is create the new `custom-mlflow` library

```
project/
|-- pyproject.toml 
|-- custom-mlflow/ 
|-- src/
```

and add the dependancy in my pyproject.toml

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "3.11.6" 
custom-mlflow = {path = "./custom-mlflow"}
```

Where I am struggling is how organize the `custom-mlflow` project.Let's say for sake of simplicity that I want to use exactly `mlflow` and just rename it `custom-mlflow`

Could you please tell me how that is usually done? Also `mlflow` can be used in the cli, does that need additional support?

Right now, this is what I think of doing:

inside the `custom-mlflow` folder, create a `__init__.py` file and just do the following:

```
from mlflow import *
```

and that's it, but I know it is not going to work. I am confused, if I need to add more layers and/or add a `setup.py` file?

should I add a `pyproject.toml` of its own for the `custom-mlflow` project?